# Android: How to achieve the glow effect when long-pressing a list item?

Tags: android, list, selector

With the default selector, long-pressing a list item causes its background to transition between two colors.

Replacing the selector with the one below removes the effect. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768977/listview-item-longclick-state-for-selector), I need an animation to reproduce it. How would I go about doing that in xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/state_pressed" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/state_focused" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/state_idle_grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code from list_selector_background :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
        <!--
                Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so
                the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state.
        -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
                android:state_pressed="true"     android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"
                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
        <item android:state_focused="true"
                android:drawable="@+drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />
</selector>
```

Found [on the web](http://code.google.com/p/nookdevs/source/browse/trunk/nookLibrary/res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml?spec=svn29&r=29).

And it uses this transition for long press clicks :

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_pressed"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_longpress"  />
</transition>
```

Found [on the web too](http://code.google.com/p/nookdevs/source/browse/trunk/customLibrary/res/drawable/list_selector_background_transition.xml?r=23) .

There is no animation for that. And remember to keep you states in the same order, or at least think about it if you swap them, order is important.

Personnally, I like when things behave in a standard way, so I would just let the standard list selector.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: does not work for more any ideas why? I applied the transition as you said, you did mean that for the "list_selector_background_transition.xml" file we add the transition that you gave in the second block of code? I did that exactly but only one color is chaged that is only "list_selector_background_pressed" is applied

Comment: @coderVishal Do you use a `RecyclerView`? **This solution only works if you use a subclass of `AbsListView`** (for example, ListView). It checks if the item background has a `TransitionDrawable` and starts the animation. That is unfortunately not the case with `RecyclerView`, you'll have to invent some mechanism to start the animation yourself.