# Have long press transition animation effect on linear layout

Tags: android

Referring to [Android: How to achieve the glow effect when long-pressing a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513301/android-how-to-achieve-the-glow-effect-when-long-pressing-a-list-item)

By applying `list_selector_holo_light.xml` on a linear layout's background (Which is NOT being used in ListView) , I thought I can achieve glowing animation effect by long press on it.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />

</selector>
```

However, I do not see the transition animation effect, to transits from light blue to dark blue.

Is there anything else I had missed out?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried to add android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" to the linear layout, to no avail: there is no animation ongoing. Android really sucks in this department.