# Android selector long press with colors

Tags: android, colors, long-press, android-selector, android-transitions

This is what I need:

A selector to show that you pressed it. But this selector also handles the long-press color transition. I looked a lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513388/2767703). This is basically what I need, but this only works with images, not colors. Here is my code right now:

default_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/default_selector_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/default_selector_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@color/selection_grey" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/selection_grey"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

default_selector_transition.xml:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_default"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_longpressed_default"  />
</transition>
```

The drawables in default_selector_transition.xml are now 9 patches. I want to know if it is possible to change this to colors.

What I tried:

- Just put a color instead of a drawable in there
- Put a color as drawable in there (`<drawable name="selection_grey_drawable">#BDBDBD</drawable>`)

I'm hoping you guys have a solution for me!

Answer (score 2):

Putting a color instead of a drawable didn't work for you?

If not, you can still try creating a separate `drawable` files with `shapes` inside. For example like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/your_color_1" />
</shape>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/your_color_2" />
</shape>
```

and then linking those files inside your `default_selector_transition.xml`:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/first_shape"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/second_shape"  />
</transition>
```

EDIT:

Well the main problem is that your code doesn't work for me at all, even with 9-patches...

Android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition) says:

> `<item>`
>   Defines a drawable to use as part of the drawable transition.
>   Must be a child of a `<transition>` element. Accepts child `<bitmap>`
>   elements.

Therefore if your code works for you, you can still try to trick `drawable` to use `bitmap` child that is being created with a color?
Something like this should work:

```
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/dummy_bitmap"
    android:tint="@color/your_color"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Where `dummy_bitmap` is just some drawable that would "fill" the needed `src` field in this bitmap.

maybe like this:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/NOT_transparent_dummy_bitmap"
            android:tint="@color/your_color_1"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/NOT_transparent_dummy_bitmap"
            android:tint="@color/your_color_2"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>
</transition>
```

Comment: I just tried this, and unfortunately this doesn't work. This could've been a good other option.

Comment: Well I just did as you said, made two files in the drawable folder. Both shapes. One is gray (#BDBDBD) and the other is darker gray (#9E9E9E). I put those shapes as you said in the transition file, but it just stays one color when long pressed

Comment: Good try, I really thought this one would work. But unfortunately it didn't. I used a transparent image and tint was gray again. This time there was no selection at all

Comment: Damn, I run out of ideas:) Good luck then:p If you find a solution, please paste it somewhere in this thread.

Comment: wait... you used transparent image? `tint` will work only if its not transparent. It can be a png file 1x1 pixels since the `tileMode="repeat"` is present (any color but not transparent)

Comment: Just tried it, but also doesn't work. Tried a white color. I think there is no easy way to do this than using images