# ListView longpress custom color

Tags: android, listview, styles

I want to customize long press color and animation when pressing on listview item in AppCompat theme. I`m using custom selector.

Here is list_selector_background_transition:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_pressed"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_longpress"  />
    </transition>
```

When press its working, but not when long pressing.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/primary"
                android:startColor="@color/accent"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

What should be done?

EDIT. item_selector.xml

```
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />
```

Comment: So where did you use your `list_selector_background_transition`?

Comment: in the item_selector, which is a background in row layout.

Comment: so what's all that gradient stuff then?

Comment: What are the color values for pressed and longpress?

Comment: I was trying to repeat that glowing effect from light blue to dark blue, just change the colors. What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: Long press is working, colors dont work as was in default. I refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513301/android-how-to-achieve-the-glow-effect-when-long-pressing-a-list-item

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the problem is unclear. You've basically copied the default list selector from the SDK, so we know that it is valid. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clearly demonstrate what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513301/android-how-to-achieve-the-glow-effect-when-long-pressing-a-list-item) will help you.

I'm guessing you need to take in mind the :state focused tag

```
<item android:state_focused="true"/>
```

Comment: I have state_focused on every line.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have created a list selector and you are using it as a background. The list selector will take precedence over the background. You should be setting it as the `listSelector` on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/item_selector" />
```

Comment: This help to move further in someway, but it is not what I was asking for. How to alter long press animation colors for AppCompat

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You were saying the long press wasn't working and now you're talking about color customization?

Comment: Long press is working, colors dont work as was in default. I refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513301/android-how-to-achieve-the-glow-effect-when-long-pressing-a-list-item

Comment: So you're saying you have the exact same behavior as when you didn't have the selector?

Comment: Exact the same, yes. No animation.