# Change bottom border color when selected a listview item

Tags: android, listview, colors, border

[image]

This screenshot is from my sms application. I just wanted to know, is it possible to change that blue border color to orange so that it matches my application theme?

I tried many things, but none of them worked. I know there is maybe something to be written in styles xml file for it, but what can I do? Anyone have an idea?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this repo : [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator_holo.xml)

It's an xml snippet regarding tabs and its colors.

Also if you need the border color for the selected items you should try this :

**Use this as the border for your items**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#yourcolorhere" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

**And this for your selector in the drawable folder:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/myBorder"          
android:state_selected="true"> <!--you can change this to android:state_pressed not selected if you're using RelativeLayout -->
    </item>
            <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
        </selector>
```

Comment: I just want to change that blue border color to orange. The code you provided will not change it because this border comes when user long tap on the list item. what to do in this case?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513301/android-how-to-achieve-the-glow-effect-when-long-pressing-a-list-item/6513388#6513388

Comment: let me check Thankyou for this sir