# Selector states for a ListItem color change on long click?

Tags: java, android, listview

What selector states do i need if i want to have my `list item` in a **different color after a long click** on it?
 (Got a `OnItemLongClickListener` to select multiple items with long click)

`state_activated="true"` does only work for a short click

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_background_selected" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_background" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513301/android-how-to-achieve-the-glow-effect-when-long-pressing-a-list-item/6513388#6513388

Comment: I already checked this question but it gave no answer for mine.