# Different state drawable in the pressed and long pressed state of item in the listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview filled by the data which has `available` and `inavailable` statuses. if an item which bind available status data is clicked, the background of the itemview will become the pressed status drawable. As well if the item bind the inavailable status data is clicked, the background will don't change。

But if i make a long press on the item **no matter it's binding data is availabe or inavaiable**, the background of it should change to the long pressed status drawable.

So how can i implement this, I had trid to use the selector, but it don't have a state means long pressed .

Comment: Possible dublicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768977/listview-item-longclick-state-for-selector

Comment: @Yahor10 it's too complicated :(, and don't fit my situation.

Comment: Use TouchEvent with timertask for long click instead selector

Comment: It's a good advise, but i should control many things, i'm looking for a simple way to achieve this.